# Is ORDER BY ordering is guaranteed with READ UNCOMMITTED?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, isolation-level

In one of the proprietary RDBMS, I found out that this query:

```sql
SELECT LastChecked, BatchId
FROM Logs
ORDER BY LastChecked ASC, BatchId ASC
```

can output results with invalid ordering:

```
...
1646605813628          12917
1646605466389          12952
...
```

I know that `LastChecked` values are being updated very actively in this table, so my guess is that it is a race condition, due to low transaction isolation level. Unfortunately, this database don't have proper documentation of transaction isolation levels, so it's only my guess (and that's why I won't name the vendor).

**Question**: is it the same for popular relational databases? Can I somehow see invalid order from query results, with lower transaction isolation level and active writes in the background?

I'm interested in:

- PostgreSQL
- MySQL
- MSSQL
- optionally others

Comment: this must be a bug. as every rdms guarantees that the order is correct at the execution time.

Comment: SO is for programming questions and so your question is mostly off topic, maybe DBA

Comment: Read Uncommited provides rows sorted according to the `ORDER BY` clause. If your database is not doing this, it may be a bug. What's the database?

Comment: I think this is totally fine as a question for Stack Overflow. SQL is a programming language, therefore you are asking about how a given sample of code works.

Comment: Why are you using READ UNCOMMITTED? I have been using SQL for 30+ years, and I've never encountered a legitimate use of READ UNCOMMITTED.

Comment: @BillKarwin The only case I've seen Read Uncommitteed suggested as useful is in an overtaxed DB2 engine where not filtering committed and uncommited rows makes the query performance bearable. I would consider this an option of last resort since the query is returning data that may not be there a second later.

Comment: @TheImpaler Understood, but IMO, there are other optimization solutions that should be used instead of making queries return potentially invalid results.

Comment: Only legitimate use I ever found for it was to obtain an *approximate* row count from a long running update process, in older versions of SQL Server. Not really the same category as this though ...

Comment: @BillKarwin Legitimate uses include querying system tables for debugging/diagnostic purposes. Agree I've never seen a legitimate use on a user table

Comment: Is the Logs table a user defined table? How are lastchecked and batchid generated for the insert, if in client code it is perfectly possible for them to be out of sync